# Picking alternate elements from Entity for different inner entity's property values and repeating them

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a `Product` entity that contains `Category` entity. Now what I am trying to achieve is a list of products where the list contains products in an order where a product from a category should come once every other category product is listed. For example: If there are three categories (cat1,cat2 and cat3) and each of them contains 2 to  3 products and the `pageSize` is 5 then the list should be like this:

- [Product1 from cat1],
- [Product2 from cat2],
- [Product3 from cat3],
- [Product4 from cat1],
- [Product5 from cat2]

Following is my code. But it is now showing the correct results.

```
var randomProducts = new List<Product>();

var categories = Products.Select(c => c.Category.ID).Distinct().ToList();
int y = categories.First();
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++)
{
    if (index == categories.Count)
        break;
    var catid = categories[index];
    var _products = Products.Skip(skipCount).ToList().Except(randomProducts).Where(c => c.Category.ID == catid);
    if(_products != null && _products.Count() > 0)
        randomProducts.Add(_products.First());
    else
    {
        index++;
    }

    if (randomProducts.Count == Products.Count())
        break;
}
return randomProducts;
```

Comment: what would happen if say your category 1 has 3 more products? where would you put the excess products?

Comment: @Josh the next product from category 1 will be listed after next product from category 2 and 3 are listed. 1,2,3,1,2,3....and so on.